# Why am I getting an uninitialized local variable error when I have already defined it?

Tags: c++, initialization

I am a beginner with c++ and I'm having trouble with this error, I am aware that this error means I am trying to use a variable that hasn't been given a value yet.

The context of the program is a that the variable is called option, the value of option is input by the user in a later function. When I started getting this error my only thought was to give the variable a value that was determined in the function so written as "option = enteroption(option);" however it still says the variable is uninitialized. can anybody help explain what I am maybe doing wrong? thanks.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Arcade game menu.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    char option; //declare variable 
    float balance; //declare variable

    const unsigned char pounds(156); //signatures for functions
    void processoption(char, float&, char);
    void payinitialfee(float&);
    char enteroption(char);


    payinitialfee(balance); //call functions
    enteroption(option); 



    while ((option != 'Q') && (balance > 0)); //while option is not Q and balance is greater than 0 call functions
    {
        processoption(option, balance, pounds);
        option = enteroption(option);
    }

    cout << "Thanks for playing." << endl;

    system("pause");
}

void payinitialfee(float& balance)
{
    balance = 100;
}

char enteroption(char option)
{
    cout << "Enter option..." << endl << "P:Play or B:Balance or Q:Quit" << endl;
    cin >> option;
    void putinUpperCase(char);
    putinUpperCase(option);

    return option;
}

void putinUpperCase(char option)
{
    option = toupper(option);
}

void processoption(char option, float&balance, char pounds)
{

    void playGame(float&); //signatures
    void showbalance(float&, char);

    switch (option)
    {
    case 'P': playGame(balance);
        break;
    case 'B': showbalance(balance, pounds);
        break;
    default: cout << "ERROR: INVALID COMMAND." << endl;
        break;
    }

}

void playGame(float& balance)
{
    cout << "Playing..." << endl;
    balance = balance - 20;
}

void showbalance(float&balance, char pounds)
{
    cout << "The current balance is... " << pounds << balance << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `const unsigned char pounds(156)` is not a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the uninitialized variable `option` to the function `enteroption` as an argument

```
option = enteroption(option);
```

This does not make any sense and the compiler points this to your.

The function can be declared like

```
char enteroption();
```

Within the function you can declare a local variable `option` that will get a value. Then this variable can be returned from the function and is assigned to the variable `option` declared in main.

Also it seems that the call of the function

```
putinUpperCase(option);
```

has no effect because the variable `option` is not passed be reference. See the function declaration

```
void putinUpperCase(char);
```

It seems the function should be declared like

```
void putinUpperCase( char & );
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right about this.

In you current code you call `option = enteroption(option)`. At this point `option` is undefined, which the compiler tells you. You either want to pass `option` by reference:

```
void enteroption(char &option)
{
    // ...
    cin >> option;
    // ...
}
```

Or don't use a parameter here:

```
char enteroption()
{
    char option;
    // ...
    cin >> option;
    // ...
    return option;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference of local member `option` from calling function instead of returning a character. The same can be applied to make upper case letter which will ultimately called function can modify the value of the argument by using its reference passed in.

```
enteroption(option);

void enteroption(char& option)
{
  cout << "Enter option..." << endl << "P:Play or B:Balance or Q:Quit" << endl;
  cin >> option;
  void putinUpperCase(char&);
  putinUpperCase(option);
  return;
}

void putinUpperCase(char& option)
{
  option = toupper(option);
}
```